# "How read part of large CSV or read it with any step"

Tags: python, visualization, data-science

I have a very large dataset with  125497040 rows and 6 columns. When I try to read the whole CSV file in pandas, my system crashes and hence I read the file in chunks.

I wanted to know is there a way to visualize the whole data by reading in chunks?

Comment: You can plot your data using `matplotlib` package and visualize it

Comment: But is it enough memory to manipulate such a huge dataset? Try to plot some chunk of it first, this may be enough

Comment: @GarbageCollector :I know I could use matplotlib, but I wanted to know if its possible to visualize the whole data set at once to see the trends and patterns. Looks like I need to do it by parts and interpret it.

Comment: @demonplus : Thank you. I guess I need to do that only.

Comment: @harshavardhan upload on hdfs and load from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not good idea to visualize all data at once, because we cannot see all chart points in one small chart. You can use any smoothing or/and approximation algorithms, or just take a point with a certain step. And you may detail this on chart zooming.

Take a look on *Plotly* https://plot.ly/javascript/zoom-events/ .

If this is a satisfactory approach for you, then it is worth reformulating the question for example to "How read part of large CSV or read it with any step". And seems, that this problem can be solve using this:

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: + you can also try to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql, https://www.r-bloggers.com/turning-data-into-awesome-with-sqldf-and-pandasql/ . It allows to work with DB directly, but I'm not sure, I've not ever used it, but you can try =)

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll try as said :)